# errors in laravel files

Tags: php, laravel

I just installed laravel for the first time [image]
andi have php 8.1

I haven't touched anything yet and I have the following errors
[image]

[image]

I don't understand these errors without having touched a single line of code.

I tried to find solutions but I don't know what to do

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: That said, it looks like your IDE isn't set to use PHP 8.1, so doesn't know what to do with the new features. You'll need to find that option in your IDE's settings

Comment: In your command line type `php -v` and paste the results here

Comment: PHP 8.1.12 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2022 18:16:21) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies